# C# class to Sql table

Tags: c#, sql-server, class

There are a lot of Sql table -> C# class methodologies, but I'm looking for the reverse.

Hypothetical situation:

I have N classes populated by some web service I consume, manipulate, then preform an action on.  Now the boss wants said web service data persisted in a database.

I already have the classes defined, how can I quickly and easily (aka, lazily) generate a sql table off of each class?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239/how-can-i-generate-database-tables-from-c-classes

Comment: Easier said than done.   How would you store STRING data in the database?  VARCHAR(<size>) -How do you know the size to use.  NVARCHAR() - Does the string need Unicode characers.  CHAR()?  Should booleans be stored as TinyInt.   Should Private members be stored?  What about GET/SET properties that convert a data type such as a flag into a literal value.      But, it would be a handy tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity Framework and nHibernate both allow you to use them in "code-first" mode, which involves writing classes then generating databases.

There is a walk-through of this on ScottGu's blog here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can use MS Entity Framework Code First approach:

> Code First allows you to define your model using C# or VB.Net classes,
>   optionally additional configuration can be performed using attributes
>   on your classes and properties or by using a Fluent API. Your model
>   can be used to generate a database schema or to map to an existing
>   database.

read more about it here: [EF 4.1 Code First Walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-code-first-walkthrough.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework 4 has a code first development feature, I haven't used it so can't really recommend it

[ScottGu blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx)