# Create SQL Server database tables from C# classes

Tags: c#, sql-server, class, ssis, xsd

Is it possible to automatically convert a lot of C# classes to SQL Server database tables ?

I need to import some xml files into SQL Server but using SSIS the runtime stops working as soon as I select the xsd file. However I easily converted the xsd to class files so that's why I am asking if its possible to have a workaround...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239/how-can-i-generate-database-tables-from-c-sharp-classes

Comment: You could always use Entity Framework code first..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I generate database tables from C# classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239/how-can-i-generate-database-tables-from-c-sharp-classes)

Answer (score 5):

You can use Entity Framework Code First functionality, with a little extra work to get the tables done in your database.

There you have a [good post on it by ScottGu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to automatically do this. Entity Framework has a model called Code First, which essentially does this: takes your C# classes and creates the database and tables automatically for you.

Take a look [at this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx) post by Scott Guthrie.

Answer (score 0):

Other option you might test is DataSet.ReadXml() function. Drawback is the Dataset can't handle complexType="mixed", but it deals well with large files (my files had about 50M each). All tables and columns are named by XML tags and relations are autogenerated by DataSet itself.