# Create SQL Server table from user-defined class

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, orm, ado.net

I am creating a mini-ORM to learn reflection better in C#.

Also I want to use **Native & Pure C#** and do not use Entity Framework or [SQL Server Management Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/sql-server-management-objects-smo-programming-guide).

```
public static void CreateTable(Type tableType, string connectionString)
{
     // codes to create table in database
}
```

The problem is the `CreateTable` method, there are lots of problems in it, for example :

- I could not find any standard way to create a table from user-defined class.
  [How can I generate database tables from C# classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239/how-can-i-generate-database-tables-from-c-sharp-classes): this solution is good but not ideal. Maybe it crashes in some situations.
- DataTypes!
  There is no integration between C# and SQL Server datatypes. For example `varchar`, `nvarchar` and `text` all are (or map to) `string` !

So when a user creates this class :

```
public class Person
{        
   public int ID { get; set; }        
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

which SQL Server datatype should I use for `Name`?

Finally if generating a SQL query and executing it is best way for this question, what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Which SQL-type should I use for Name ???

If you're looking at Entity Framework as an example to follow, by default they map `System.String` to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in all cases. Using property attributes in the Code First entity model (e.g. `[Column(DbType = "CHAR(10)")]` allows the developer to explicity specify column types.

Maybe you could follow this approach and default to the all encompassing `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for all strings and create some simple attributes within your ORM for special cases. You wont know string lengths until runtime, after all.

Comment: Thank you , and I should generate SQL query for creating table ? Is there another solution instead of generating query ? because it is not accurate .

Comment: You mean should you send [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) to SQL Server to create the tables? Yes, I believe that's the only way you can.